# Reduce size of swf from Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I have created a simple Flash Builder 4.6 project containing a simple button, and i have exported the project with release option, with mx namespaces.

The problem is that the file size is aboud 266 kb with the compile option: Merged into the application. I use only a simple button. My question is there is a way to remove any reference to mx library that i don't use in my code in order to reduce the swf size.

Answer (score 2):

The option "Merged into code" will actually already figure out what needs to be compiled into the application and strip out code that you don't use. As a test, try adding another different component and create another release build. You'll notice that the filesize is bigger.

The best way to reduce the swf size is to use Runtime shared libraries (RSLs). This is the default linkage option of the SDK.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=projects_7.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:
Project -> Properties -> Flex Build Path

Make sure the combo "Framework linkage" is selected with the value: 'Merged into the code'.

Below you should have a tree named "Build Path Libraries".
Expand the first node. Then try to remove the libraries by selecting the relative node and clicking on the Remove Button on the right